# shiny server cannot open the connection when trying to include RMarkDown

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown, shiny-server, shinydashboard

I was trying to insert some rmd files into my shiny dashboard. Everything works fine locally. But when I tried it on my shiny server, it shows:

> Warning in file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) :
>     cannot open file 'testing.md': Permission denied
>   Warning: Error in file: cannot open the connection

it's just a very simple testing shiny dashboard:

app.R

```
library(shiny)
library(knitr)
library(shinydashboard)

setwd("/srv/shiny-server/docs/test2")

rmdfiles = c("testing.Rmd")
sapply(rmdfiles, knit, quiet = T)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "testing"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("Dashboard", tabName = "dashboard", icon = icon("dashboard")),
      menuItem("Widgets", tabName = "widgets", icon = icon("th"))
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      tabItem(
        tabName = "dashboard",
        uiOutput("testing")
      ),

      tabItem(
        tabName = "widgets",
        234
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$testing <- renderUI({
    includeMarkdown("testing.md")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

and testing.rmd is just the sample rmd.

Anybody have some ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure this works locally? From a quick glance through what you've posted, I would start by changing the server portion to *includeMarkdown("testing.Rmd")*, the file listed in your current code is ".md" and that's also the file extension showing up in the Warning you're seeing.